# Problem with Unity's Raycasting object detection 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, detection, raycasting

So im trying to make an enemy **AI** which detects a player with the unity *raycaster*. The **AI** is, while working, detecting the player even if its miles further away than I would like. Could you help me?
also I'm getting a `Rigidbody2D` and a player target. The `seeDistance` is 2

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;
    private bool movingRight = true;
    public bool SeenPlayer = false;
    public Transform target;
    public float seeDistance;
    public int health = 3;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public Transform groundDetection; 

    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (SeenPlayer == false)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        }

        RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, Vector2.down, 2f);
        RaycastHit2D SeePlayer = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, Vector2.left, seeDistance);
        if (groundInfo.collider == false)
        {
            if (movingRight == true)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
                movingRight = false;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                movingRight = true;
            }
        }
        if (SeePlayer)
        {
            SeenPlayer = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        BulletScript bullet = collision.GetComponent<BulletScript>();
        if (bullet != null)
        {
            //Destroy(gameObject);-
            health -= 1;
            Destroy(bullet.gameObject);
            if (health == 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(4, 2), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to reset `SeenPlayer` when `SeePlayer` is false.  You could just use `SeenPlayer = SeePlayer`.

Comment: No the variable aint the problem. The problem is with the Raycaster. Setting `SeenPlayer` to `SeePlayer`, when `SeePlayer` doesnt work, wont work. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in:

```
if(SeePlayer){
    SeenPlayer = true;
}
```

SeePlayer is of type RaycastHit2D (a struct). Struct is never null so the condition

```
if(SeePlayer)
```

is always meet. You should probably check if the collider inside is valid:

```
if(SeePlayer.collider)
```

EDIT:
I suppose

```
if(SeePlayer != default(RaycastHit2D))
```

Would do the job too